# Getting my code into TFS using local Git repo

Tags: git, tfs

I am currently using the TFS Integration plugin for my test automation code. However, when I make an update to my local source code, the code also gets updated immediately on the TFS server. I have Git installed locally and would like to it to sync the commit, pull, push into TFS. What is the procedure to sync these two repositories?

Comment: What client do you use? Visual Studio or any other Git client? Genearlly if you are using VS and local Git, you just need to publish the local Git repo to remote TFS.

Answer (score 0):

To update the changes on the TFS server you have to **Check in** (TFVC) or **Push** (Git) the changes into TFS.

So, if you are using local Git, then you just need to add the origin remote:

**For Git bash:**

1. Create a Git repository in TFS.
2. Remove the existing origin and then add the tfs origin:

   `git remote -v
   git remote remove origin
   git remote add origin http://server：8080/tfs/collectionlc/_git/xxx
   git push origin`

**For VS Team Explorer:**

Okay, I was apparently overcomplicating this. Here's what I did.

1. Created a new project in TFService
2. Connected to that project in Visual Studio
3. Cloned that project in Visual Studio
4. `git pull c:\source\oldGitProject`

It will pull all of the changes from the old location.

Reference: [Moving an existing Git Repository to TFService/TFS 2013](http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/moving-existing-git-repository-tfservicetfs-2013/)

Comment: @user2643607 Have you resolved the issue? any update?